# Dynamically created Bootsrap cards not getting grid display styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have an issue where Bootstrap cards that are created dynamically with external Firebase data through vanilla js aren't displayed properly in a container. The cards have all the right classes, but the bootstrap style used for aligning the cards in a grid is not getting applied to new cards, resulting in them just appearing over other cards in the upper left corner. It would really be great if someone could help me out with this.

Here is the code for the div in which the cards get inserted, these are default cards that are hardcoded.

```
<!-- Cards Dashboard  -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card-container-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-container" >
                        <div class="row g-3" id="card-container">
                            <!-- Single Card  -->
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-3 card-thumbnail all sarajevo">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/kontejneri.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Location  -->
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"> <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i> Sarajevo</li>                                        
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="card-body">                                        
                                        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
                                    </div>
    
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <!-- Single Card  -->
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-3 card-thumbnail all zenica">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/asphalt.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Location  -->
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"> <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i> Zenica</li>                                        
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="card-body">                                        
                                        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
                                    </div>
    
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                          
    
                            <!-- Single Card  -->
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-3 card-thumbnail all sarajevo">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/manhole.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Location  -->
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"> <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i> Sarajevo</li>                                        
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="card-body">                                        
                                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
                                    </div>
    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        
    
                            <!-- Single Card  -->
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-3 card-thumbnail all zenica">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/rupa.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some text here</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
                                    </div>
        
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Here is the js code which gets the data from the database and creates a new card:

```
 onValue(ref(database, 'Report Data/'), (snapshot) => {
            console.log('snapshot:', snapshot.val());
            //snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            const childData = snapshot.val();
                // Create new HTML elements to display the data
                const card = document.createElement('div');
                const cardCol = document.createElement('div');
                const cardBody = document.createElement('div');
                const image = document.createElement('img');
                const cardTitle = document.createElement('h5');
                const cardText = document.createElement('p');
                const cardLink = document.createElement('a');

                // Set the attributes of the HTML elements
                card.classList.add('col-12', 'col-md-6', 'col-lg-3', 'mt-3', 'card-thumbnail');
                cardCol.classList.add('card');
                cardBody.classList.add(`card-body`);
                image.classList.add('card-img-top');
                cardTitle.classList.add('card-title');
                cardText.classList.add('card-text');
                cardLink.classList.add('btn');
                cardLink.href = '#';
                image.src = childData.Image_URL;
                cardTitle.innerHTML = childData.Title;
                cardText.innerHTML = childData.Description;
                cardLink.innerText = 'Pročitaj više';

                // Add the HTML elements to the card
                card.appendChild(cardCol);
                cardCol.appendChild(image);
                cardCol.appendChild(cardBody);
                cardBody.appendChild(cardTitle);
                cardBody.appendChild(cardText);
                cardCol.appendChild(cardBody);
                cardBody.appendChild(cardLink);

               
                // Add the card to the page
                document.getElementById('card-container').appendChild(card);
                console.log(`Card added`);
                $(card).card();
            });
```

Default cards get an automatic style property as soon as the page loads, the dynamically generated cards do not. If anyone could help me out with this it would be great.

Expected: Have the dynamically created cards appear in the grid with other cards.
Resulted: Dynamically created cards appear on top of other cards outside of the bootstrap grid.